My notion input is failing to authenticate despite correct key?
I'm trying to write some code to build a calendar on notion for myself. I wrote the following code but getting this authentication error:
"raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://www.notion.so/api/v3/loadUserContent"

I don't fully understand the error message but appears to be authentication related.
I've written the full code here (obviously not added my key in, however I have double verified I'm using the correct integration key and refreshed it also)
from notion.client import NotionClient

# Your integration token
integration_token = "MYKEY"

# Authenticate with Notion API
client = NotionClient(token_v2=integration_token)

# Create a new page
calendar_page = client.get_user().get_workspace().add_page(title="365-Day Calendar")

# Create a table block
calendar_table = calendar_page.children.add_new("collection_view")

# Set up the schema for the table
calendar_table.collection = client.get_collection("block")
calendar_table.views.add_new(view_type="table")
schema = calendar_table.collection.add_schema_properties({"Name": {"type": "title"}})

# Add a property for mood
schema = calendar_table.collection.add_schema_properties({"Mood": {"type": "select", "options": [
    {"name": " Good"}, {"name": " Bad"}
]}})

# Update each row with the Mood property
for row in calendar_table.collection.get_rows():
    row.set_property("Mood", " Good")  # Set default mood to Good

# Add a property for month
schema = calendar_table.collection.add_schema_properties({"Month": {"type": "select", "options": [
    {"name": "January"}, {"name": "February"}, {"name": "March"}, {"name": "April"}, {"name": "May"}, {"name": "June"},
    {"name": "July"}, {"name": "August"}, {"name": "September"}, {"name": "October"}, {"name": "November"}, {"name": "December"}
]}})

# Update each row with the Month property
for row in calendar_table.collection.get_rows():
    # Extract month from the date
    month = row.title.split('-')[1]
    row.set_property("Month", month)

# Add title with the year
calendar_table.title = "2024"

Anyone have any ideas?
